# Loading JWplayer dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi and thanks for looking into this.

I have a code I've been working on to add videos to my site. All videos are from youtube. Once a user has clicked on submit, a link becomes visible. When clicking on it the user can preview the video.

One week ago I used the following to achieve this:

```
$("#result").html('<a href="javascript:initPlayer(\'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXhy7ZsiR50\')>Preview video</a><br>');
```

Everything worked fine. But today I was trying the script and the link doesn't appear anymore. The link works however fine if I do something like:

```
<a href="javascript:initPlayer('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXhy7ZsiR50')">Preview video</a>
```

Somewhere on the page.

I don't know why the call with jQuery doesn't work anymore. It worked fine when I was developing the website. I tried it on different browsers, but with the same result in the end.

Anyone any idea how to solve this? I'm starting to pull out my hair. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
$("#result").html("<a href='javascript:initPlayer(\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXhy7ZsiR50\")'>Preview video</a><br>");
```

I think it's a double/single quotes problem. Everything is back to normal.